# script to include like and unlike option with every mysql fetched result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
    //Outputs the data
    Echo "<b>".$info['name'] . " </b> :-<br>"; 
    include('db.php');
    $postid = 1;
    $data = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query('SELECT  `like` , `unlike` FROM posts WHERE id=" '.$postid.' "  '));
    Echo "<html><body><a href='javascript:;' onclick='doAction($postid,like);'>Like (<span id='<?php echo $postid;?>_likes'>$data->like</span>)</a></html></body>";
    Echo "<html><body><a href='javascript:;' onclick='doAction($postid,unlike);'>Unlike (<span id='<?php echo $postid;?>_unlikes'>$data->unlike</span>)</a></html></body>";
}
```

In the above script I have included `like` and `unlike` option with every fetched result.

I get the following result: `like (0)unlike (0)`

Every thing works perfectly. The only problem is that it doesn't increment when clicked on.

Please help me.

It works perfect in the simple code shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function doAction(postid,type){
                $.post('doAjax.php' , {postid:postid, type:type}, function(data){
                    $('#'+postid+'_'+type+'s').text(data);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include('db.php');
            $postid = 1;

            $data = mysql_fetch_object( mysql_query( 'SELECT  `like` , `unlike` FROM posts WHERE id= " ' . $postid . ' " ' ) );
        ?>
        <p>hello</p>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="doAction('<?php echo $postid; ?>','like');">Like (<span id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_likes"><?php echo $data->like; ?></span>)</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="doAction('<?php echo $postid; ?>','unlike');">Unlike    (<span id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_unlikes"><?php echo $data->unlike; ?></span>)</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also want to use `PDO` instead of `mysql_fetch` for the script shown above .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but **stop usign mysql_query**! Use **[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**! Using mysql_query like a lot of people do will leave you wide open for SQL Injection.

Comment: and `doAjax.php` what does it include ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the 2 lines "Echo <html...> with:

```
echo "<div><a href='javascript:;' onclick='doAction($postid,like);'>Like (<span id='{$postid}_likes'>{$data->like}</span>)</a></div>";
echo "<div><a href='javascript:;' onclick='doAction($postid,unlike);'>Unlike (<span id='{$postid}_unlikes'>{$data->unlike}</span>)</a></div>";
```

Other issues:
-avoid using mysql_query, use PDO as suggested

-the query inside a loop will lead to poor performance. you should have a single query that gets the info and the likes (using JOINs). And inside the loop display the likes for each info.

Comment: can anybody show the PDO script for the mysql_fetch used in the first script of this page.